# В чем может быть проблема выравнивания через row; col?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужно сделать сетку. Прописал код, но он выравнивает именно вертикально, впритык.  Пытался удалять и сокращать `col`, но изображения становятся огромными.

Буду рад очень помощи!

Версия bootstrap : v4.1.3

Код прикреплю, пример тоже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<section id="catalog">
  <section class="product-area section-padding" style="
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-bottom: 60px;
            ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="section-title-heading">
              <h2 style="
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 100;
"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-contents fadeIn wow" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/97bdc3d4767a4104a0b5db068df2c9d6.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-contents fadeIn wow" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/eaf70216c2a547bdacdf91e65d289af5.jpg" alt="2" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-contents fadeIn wow" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/fec8ffd80a73458bb53a872f795d8fb5.jpg" alt="3" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-contents fadeIn wow" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/d7c60f274d8542299170029026519a0b.jpg" alt="4" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-contents fadeIn wow" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/3739158971da413fad17b6c87b7ec6d4.jpg" alt="5" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-contents fadeIn wow" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/9a264d04f13b4b8d86052c4f74ba5f09.jpg" alt="6" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Ребят, почти нашел решение (код), но теперь почему-то размеры второй колонки стали меньше ( скриншот):

```html
  <section id="catalog">
                <section class="product-area section-padding" style="
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-bottom: 60px;
            ">
               <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/97bdc3d4767a4104a0b5db068df2c9d6.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/eaf70216c2a547bdacdf91e65d289af5.jpg" alt="2" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/fec8ffd80a73458bb53a872f795d8fb5.jpg" alt="3" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/d7c60f274d8542299170029026519a0b.jpg" alt="4" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/3739158971da413fad17b6c87b7ec6d4.jpg" alt="5" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/9a264d04f13b4b8d86052c4f74ba5f09.jpg" alt="6" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
</section>
```

[image: почти нашел решение]

Вот этот код теперь делает, все наоборот

```html
          <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/97bdc3d4767a4104a0b5db068df2c9d6.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/eaf70216c2a547bdacdf91e65d289af5.jpg" alt="2" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/fec8ffd80a73458bb53a872f795d8fb5.jpg" alt="3" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/d7c60f274d8542299170029026519a0b.jpg" alt="4" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/3739158971da413fad17b6c87b7ec6d4.jpg" alt="5" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/9a264d04f13b4b8d86052c4f74ba5f09.jpg" alt="6" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

И получается вот что [image: Шикарно прост]

Так, мы почти нашли решение

```html
<section id="catalog">
  <section class="product-area section-padding" style="
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-bottom: 60px;
            ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="/Storage/imgs/97bdc3d4767a4104a0b5db068df2c9d6.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%" height="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="/Storage/imgs/eaf70216c2a547bdacdf91e65d289af5.jpg" alt="2" style="width:100%" height="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="/Storage/imgs/fec8ffd80a73458bb53a872f795d8fb5.jpg" alt="3" style="width:100%" height="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/d7c60f274d8542299170029026519a0b.jpg" alt="4" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/3739158971da413fad17b6c87b7ec6d4.jpg" alt="5" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/9a264d04f13b4b8d86052c4f74ba5f09.jpg" alt="6" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Но почему размеры такие я не понимаю [image: Размеры поплыли]

Итак, решение было найдено

```html
      <section id="catalog">
                <section class="product-area section-padding" style="
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-bottom: 60px;
            ">
               <div class="container">
               <div class="row text-center">
                   <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <img src="/Storage/imgs/97bdc3d4767a4104a0b5db068df2c9d6.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <img src="/Storage/imgs/eaf70216c2a547bdacdf91e65d289af5.jpg" alt="2" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <img src="/Storage/imgs/fec8ffd80a73458bb53a872f795d8fb5.jpg" alt="3" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                   </div>
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/d7c60f274d8542299170029026519a0b.jpg" alt="4" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/3739158971da413fad17b6c87b7ec6d4.jpg" alt="5" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="/Storage/imgs/9a264d04f13b4b8d86052c4f74ba5f09.jpg" alt="6" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Лишний тег `<div class="row text-center">` в середине кода, и лишний закрывающий `</section>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<section id="catalog">
  <section class="product-area section-padding" style="
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-bottom: 60px;
            ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="section-title-heading">
              <h2 style="
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 100;
"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
          <div class="product-contents fadeIn wow" style="visibility: visible">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/97bdc3d4767a4104a0b5db068df2c9d6.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
          <div class="product-contents fadeIn wow" style="visibility: visible">
            <img src="/Storage/imgs/97bdc3d4767a4104a0b5db068df2c9d6.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Сначала row, затем col и уже внутри col реализация карточки

Comment: Спасибо, а зачем вы сделали col-md-3 col-xs-6, именно вторая запись вообще не понятно, что она выполняет, буду признателен за ответ!

Comment: `.col-xs-6` говорит о том, что на мобильных устройствах будет занято 6 колонок. Но с версии выше 3, `-xs-` уже убран.

Comment: Сделал по вашему коду, получилось, что все фотографии отдалились, размеры уменьшились + ничего не изменилось по состоянию с 2 линией фотографий, т.е. на том же месте, что и на скриншоте :с

Comment: так у меня не 3 версия, а 4, сейчас подключена.

Comment: @Anton xs - параметры отображения до 767px, sm - до 992px, md - до 1999px, lg - всё что больше. Цифра в классе определяет размеры относительно row, X/12. подредактировал твой код в вопросе (2-ой), пробуй

Comment: @dev_null по коду который кто-то отредактировал, теперь 2 линия колонок стоит нормально, а вот первая вниз .. добавлю скриншот

Comment: Данный код не работает, он просто выводит 2 фотографии рядом, остальные же пропадают вовсе. ( ну третья тоже есть, но она очень маленькая и находится ниже под первыми двумя.

Comment: Решение было найдено, всем спасибо за участие и помощь! Действительно, глупый вопрос, но в обучение больше никак нельзя )